How to Detect the Uploaded Image Face that Matches Faces in Local Images
I have developed an Angular application that uses face-api.js for face recognition. The application processes a set of local images to identify faces and generates corresponding face descriptors.
When a new image is uploaded, the application detects and extracts the face descriptor from the uploaded image, then compares it against the descriptors of the local images to find and return all images containing matching faces
 selectedFile: any;
  localImages = ['assets/photo/face1.png', 'assets/photo/face2.png', 'assets/photo/faces.jpg']; // Add paths to your local images
  faceDescriptors: faceapi.LabeledFaceDescriptors[] = [];
  images: string[] = [];

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.loadModels();
    await this.loadLocalImages();
  }

  async loadModels() {
    try {
      await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri('/assets/models');
      await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/assets/models');
      await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/assets/models');
      console.log('Models loaded successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading models:', error);
    }
  }

  async loadLocalImages() {
    try {
      for (const imagePath of this.localImages) {
        const img = await faceapi.fetchImage(imagePath);
        const detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor();
        if (detections) {
          const label = imagePath; // Use image file path as label
          this.faceDescriptors.push(new faceapi.LabeledFaceDescriptors(label, [detections.descriptor]));
          console.log(`Loaded descriptor for ${label}:`, detections.descriptor);
        } else {
          console.log(`No face detected in ${imagePath}`);
        }
      }
      console.log('Local images loaded and processed:', this.faceDescriptors);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading local images:', error);
    }
  }

  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    console.log('File selected:', this.selectedFile);
  }

  async onUpload() {
    if (this.selectedFile) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = async () => {
        try {
          const imageBlob = this.dataURLToBlob(reader.result as string);
          if (imageBlob) {
            const img = await faceapi.bufferToImage(imageBlob);
            const detection = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor();
            if (detection) {
              console.log('Uploaded image descriptor:', detection.descriptor);
              const faceMatcher = new faceapi.FaceMatcher(this.faceDescriptors);
              const threshold = 0.6; // Adjust this value as needed

              // Find matches based on the threshold
              const matchedImageURLs = this.faceDescriptors
                .filter(descriptor => faceMatcher.findBestMatch(detection.descriptor).distance < threshold)
                .map(descriptor => descriptor.label);

              if (matchedImageURLs.length > 0) {
                console.log('Matched image URLs:', matchedImageURLs);
                this.images = matchedImageURLs;
              } else {
                this.images = [];
                console.log('No exact matches found.');
              }
            } else {
              this.images = [];
              console.log('No face detected in the uploaded image.');
            }
          } else {
            this.images = [];
            console.error('Failed to convert Data URL to Blob.');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error processing uploaded image:', error);
        }
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile);
    }
  }



The current issue with this code is that it does not return the matching face images.
